# Using "users" command gets my name 2 times?

Tags: 14.04, command-line

I was looking for some shell commands, and I took a look in "users" command.

I was hoping to get only 1 name, but I got 2:

```
nori@nori-hidamari:~$ users
nori nori
```

And when I run the command "who"

```
nori@nori-hidamari:~$ who
nori     :0           2015-04-09 09:31 (:0)
nori     pts/0        2015-04-09 09:48 (:0)
```

Is this behaviour normal? Or it's bad?

Thank you guys for helping me.

Comment: Do you have three terminals open?

Comment: @muru just updated it now. I had 2 more terminals. But still, I'm getting my user 2 times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is normal expected behaviour.

You see your user name twice because you are logged in twice.

```
[simmel]@[mars]$ users
simmel simmel
```

The second command

```
who
```

shows which user is online right now and it looks like you were online at that time with Graphical Display `:0` and `pts/0` (a terminal window).

```
[simmel]@[mars]$ who
simmel   tty8         2015-03-30 11:15 (:0)
simmel   pts/3        2015-04-09 14:16 (:0)
```

After opening some more terminals it looks like this:

```
[simmel]@[mars]$ who
simmel   tty8         2015-03-30 11:15 (:0)
simmel   pts/3        2015-04-09 14:16 (:0)
simmel   pts/4        2015-04-09 14:54 (:0)
simmel   pts/8        2015-04-09 14:54 (:0)
```

After opening more windows the count goes up in users:

```
[simmel]@[mars]$ users
simmel simmel simmel simmel
```

Comment: The output of `users` is *not* `username group`.

Comment: ops you are right ^^ I will change that

Comment: Excellent answer!  Upvoted *and* edited!  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It is normal. You will have an entry for the graphical desktop you have logged into (labeled with the corresponding `DISPLAY` - in this case `:0`), and one each for each terminal you have open (labeled with the pseudo-terminal corresponding to each of them (`pts/X`)). Since you're running this command in a terminal, you will of course have one entry corresponding to that terminal, hence a minimum of two.